# Laravel 9: Use private/presence channels with custom auth system without users

Tags: laravel, authorization, access-token, laravel-echo

I am currently trying to get Laravel's private channel broadcast system up and running for some kind of realtime messaging/monitoring system for a third-party software. We can't use public channels, because clients should be able to join specific rooms and only view/write messages inside that room.

The problem: we can't use Laravel's default authentication workflow with DB users. The laravel system is some lightweight authentication layer for a third-party system. The third-party system makes authentication control requests to laravel which then checks for a valid access token. The third party system does not send any headers or cookies from the client so we need to have to put auth information in the GET request URL (the client's token). The third party system just resends the URL it gets from the client to laravel, nothing else. Laravel then needs to authorize the request according to the url (inlcuding query parameters), IP-Adress and so on. No client headers, no cookies.

So our system only has temporary 'clients' which get access to the system using a secret redirect link which redirects with a token (no username/password, no actual login, no registration needed). So there are no users in the database, just access tokens which authorize temporary clients (actually a credentials table and a client table) and a cookie containing an encrypted token. The encrypted token is then validated against the temporary client in the database. The system does not contain any user-sensitive data and the customer does not want that users need to register. So changing the auth system to a classic user registration process is out of scope.

Sadly, the laravel docs say that to authorize private channels you need to authorize the user:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

But innstead of doing this (example of the docs):

```
Broadcast::channel('orders.{orderId}', function ($user, $orderId) {
    return $user->id === Order::findOrNew($orderId)->user_id;
});
```

I need to do something like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('room.{roomId}', function ($request) {
    $accessToken = $request->cookie('token);
    $valid = Token::where('value', '=', $accessToken)->exists();
    return $valid;
});
```

The problem: I don't know how to set this up and the docs are not that helpful. I was reading about setting up a custom auth/user provider or setting up a custom auth guard, but it seems a bit like overcomplicating this process. Also it does not solve the problem, because I need some request information which doesn't seem to get injected into the broadcast authorization route. Requests to join a private channel without being logged in as an actual user also directly results in a 40x status code and get rejected without calling the actual auth callback.

Can anyone help me out?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

**1 app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**

//Add your custom driver

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Auth::viaRequest('broadcasting-auth', function ($request) {
        **// put here your auth logic**
        return Manager::where('api_token', $request->headers->get('token'))->first();
    });
}
```

**2 config/auth.php**

//add your auth guard

```
'guards' => [
    ...
    'broadcasting' => [
        'driver' => 'broadcasting-auth',
    ],
],
```

**3 app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

// Add middleware with your custom guard

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:broadcasting']]);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

**4 routes/channels.php**

// Update channel routes

```
Broadcast::channel('manager.{id}', function ($manager, $id) {
    return (int) $manager->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Comment: What is Manager?

Comment: My custom Model. You may use the User Model or any other Model, or put your logic without any Model.

Comment: Thank you. Back then we ended up with registering users as guests after clicking on a specific link. Later on we are purging the guest users with a scheduled command so the database is not getting crowded. Maybe we will give this a try. Currently I don't have the time to try it out, but it looks like it should work.